# How to know that a posterior probability is significant in bayesian inference

Tags: probability, bayesian

First of all I would like to apologize if I am making any misconceptions or not using the right vocabulary since I am just getting started in Bayesian inference.

That said, the problem I am facing is the classification of a series of devices in different classes using the measurements that they are reporting. In order to do that, I am using the new evidences (data reported by the devices) to obtain the likelihood probability for each class with which I then obtain the posterior probability for each class. As we know, the posterior probabilities of each class obtained by the Bayes inference will sum 1. In this sense, to finally classify to which class each device belongs, I am taking the hypothesis for which the posterior probability is higher.

The problem is that, sometimes, the posterior probabilities are too close to each other so the probability of the hypothesis with the maximum posterior probability is not significant compared with the others.

Example: imagine that we have three hypotheses with the posterior probabilities being 0.4, 0.3 and 0.3. Currently I am classifying the device to the first class based on these probabilities but, as can be seen, the three probabilities are too close each other, not being any of them significant to the others.

In this sense, is there any test that I can perform to obtain if the maximum posterior probability is significant enough to the rest of them?

Thanks in advance and sorry again if I am making any mistake with the vocabulary or any misconception.

Comment: 1. I'm not sure what you mean by "significant" in this case.  2. What would you want to do as an alternative to classifying the device in the class with the highest posterior probability?  Classify it in a class with a lower posterior probability?   Any argument you can make against the first decision applies with greater force against the second decision, it seems to me.

Comment: Why don you want to choose the hypothesis with the highest posterior probability?? I think in the end of the day if you want to answer which class is more likely, it has to be the one with the highest probability no matter what the difference is between the classes.

Comment: @jbowman By significant I mean that the value of the highest posterior probability class is large enough compared with the other classes to consider that the device is in this class with high confidence. Of course I will not classify the device in other class with lower posterior probability as an alternative, is just to make knowledge that the result of the classification may not have enough confidence without needing to see the posterior probabilities of the rest of the hypothesis. This is, to have a way to identify these cases.

Comment: @Fiodor1234 Of course I will choose the hypothesis with the highest posterior probability as the result. I just want to know if there is a way to identify the cases in which the posterior probability with the highest value is not significant enough compared with the other ones, which might mean that the classification could be wrong. The thing is that I would like to known if there is any kind of test to identify these cases. I know that a rule-based algorithm may be enough but I thought that this situation could be usual and there may be a "formal" way to identify these cases.

Comment: Why not use the odds ratio between the two classes?

Comment: You know what the probability is that the classification is wrong: it's 1 - the probability that it's right, i.e., the probability of the class that you are assigning the device to!

Comment: Because your posterior probabilities sum to 1, do you use a Dirichlet prior and derive a Dirichlet posterior??

Answer (score 1):

I think you could approach this in two different ways.  The first way you would select a certain hypothesis as the default choice and only if its posterior probability is below a certain threshold would you choose against it.  This would mimic frequentist null hypothesis testing and is similar to Go/No-Go decisions in phase 2 clinical development.  A second way you could proceed is to always select the hypothesis with the largest posterior probability, regardless of how close it is in size to the posterior probability of competing hypotheses.  This is similar to early phase clinical dose finding studies.  I don't think there is a right or wrong approach.

Answer (score 1):

The criteria for 'significant'/'not significant' in a Neyman–Pearsonian hypothesis test are based on the error rate characteristics of the test, determined in advance of seeing the data. (See this for an explanation of hypothesis tests and p-values: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286) The dichotomy is not as universal or as useful as many beginner statisticians think.

With a Bayesian posterior you usually do not have access to the error rate considerations and so the 'significant'/'not significant' dichotomy is usually not applicable.

You might choose to set up criteria for inclusion into a set of classes for your devices on the basis of probability ratios for a specified hypothesis (i.e. a parameter in the statistical model that makes up the x-axis of your likelihood functions) compared to the maximally probable hypothesis but you must not call it 'significant'/'not significant'! However, the characteristics of the test that you invent would be generally unknown and so the utility and desirability of such a procedure would need to be explored.

Perhaps you should be asking a different question. Explain your data and inferential objectives and ask for suggestions as to how you might proceed. It might be that a Bayesian posterior is appropriate, but that is not clear to me.

(You failed to say anything about the prior used to convert the likelihoods into posterior probabilities. That is bad practice.)